# Difference between shall and should in this specific context?

Tags: modal-verbs

Should we go?
Shall we go?
Do they differ in their degrees of politeness?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to hear the second one in day-to-day conversation, but not because it isn't polite.

Comment: @J.R. Are you suggesting shall is outdated/formal? Is there no other difference?

Comment: I'd guess the second one is quite common in British English. I'm not even a native though.

Comment: @SandeepDhamija - No difference in meaning, really. And _shall_ does sound too formal for everyday conversation. (I'm imagining a context such as: _They're having a sale down a the department store tomorrow. Should we go?_ Other contexts may have different interpretations.)

Answer (score 1):

I practice both but then out of those two, *should* is more polite, at least in BrE (and so in InE as I know) especially when used with *I* or *we*. OALD defines it:

> [should (#10)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/should) - *(British English, formal) used with I and we in polite requests*

On the other hand, *shall* when used with *I* or *we*, OALD describes it -

> [shall (#2)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shall) - *used in questions with I and we for making offers or suggestions or asking advice.*

Answer (score 1):

To me -

> *Should* we go?

is requesting a decision about going, *what you might do*. For example:

> It is getting late, *should* we go to the store?

The reply could be yes or no.

Then if the reply is yes, you finish what you are doing, grab your wallet, etc., and say to your friend:

> *Shall* we go (now)?

which directly indicates *when* you are going.

Both are reasonably polite.

Comment: +1 But I'd say *shall we go* is an invitation or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

*Shall* is equivalent to *will* when used indicatively.  The difference in politeness is great, at least in AmE.  It has a very formal flavor to it, and you can sound snobbish if you overuse it or use this in a non-formal or non-polite context.

> I will go to the park tomorrow.
>
> I shall go to the park tomorrow.
>
> I wonder what the weather will do.
>
> I wonder what the weather shall do.
>
> I certainly shall have looked everywhere by then.

Interrogatively, *shall* heavily implies "Will you allow" or "will we allow?"  So "Shall you X" doesn't work.  "Shall we X" does work, though.

> Will Mary come with us?
>
> Shall Mary come with us?
>
> Will you take a look at this?
>
> Shall you take a look at this?  (sounds really weird.)
>
> Shall we take a look at this? (we are asking if we will allow ourselves to look at this.)

There are some arcane outmoded(?) rules about when to use *shall* and *will*, e.g. I think something about you are supposed to use *shall* for first person, etc.  It could be why you can't ask *Shall you X*.  But you can say "You shall go to the park at 3pm" in the same way as "You will go to the park at 3pm."

Answer (score -2):

When you say "Should we go" is more polite than "Shall we go". The last one is more used when you want to **give an order** to someone while the first one seems like you are **asking for** someone to go to somewhere with you.

Comment: @Downvoter- I would like you know your opinion.

Comment: It's an understandable mistake.  *Shall* in questions has a different interpretation than *shall* in statements.  In questions, it's closer to "should" in meaning.